# How to access child parent divs with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, parent-child

I have multiple div id,s = slide

I am clicking on the `<a id=medium>` and want to check if a picture or if the `rsImg class` (in the slide div) is exisiting (check if picture is in the div)

[image]

```
var test = $('#slide').children().hasClass('rsImg');
```

this returns true - guess I have to add a $this but can't find the solution

regards

Comment: Please don't post images of code; they're not SEO friendly. Post the actual code.

Comment: to access child parent divs with jquery, you can use a combination of
http://api.jquery.com/parent/,
http://api.jquery.com/find/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use find method to get the jQuery object instead of hasClass.

```
var test = $('#slide').children().find('.rsImg');
```

Or you can simply use use descendant selector.

```
var test = $('#slide .rsImg')
```

Comment: but I am getting always the same object from the same div id slide - somewhere add $this ?

Comment: You cna use $(this) in side event. You can use eq() to get speicific lement like $('#slide .rsImg').eq(0) for first, $('#slide .rsImg').eq(1) for second...

Comment: If you have multiple `slide` elements, use a class name instead: ` if($(this).parents('.slide').find('img').length)`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a#medium').on('click', function(){
    if($(this).parents('#slide').find('img').length) {
        //Do some cool stuff here
    }
});
```

Comment: var img = $(this).closest('.rsSlide').find('img'); - the closest function was also pretty helpful..